# Best way to Load Data in data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

We are building a new near realtime(refreshed every 10 minutes) hospital data warehouse from scratch. Data lies on an oracle database and we are planning to use SSIS packages to extract data from Oracle and load in the SQL Server database. I am very new with DWHousing and need suggestions on building the DWH.

Questions :

1. When extracting the data from Oracle should I import the complete tables or should I get only selected columns which I want?
   For example : If I have person,address,facility_hist tables should I join them in the extracting package and only get the selected columns? or should I extract all three tables separately in staging area and then combine them and load them in SQL Server.

2)Indexes should be created on the target tables or while extracting the data?

3. I am planning to do the initial load in batches by using the create_dt_tm for the records and load the data in months. Once everything is loaded, we are planning to use the updt_dt_tm and load any updates done in last 10 minutes.
4. Is connecting to the database a good idea to get the data every 10 minutes?

Image shows DWH ETL SSIS Package I am planning to use (instead of flat file I'll be connecting it to the oracle DB)

[image]

Comment: For a ten minute refresh cycle you're definitely going to work out an incremental data load method. The easiest way to do this is identify an existing field in the source that records whenever a record is changed. If you have this, then your incremental load is going to be a lot faster and more likely to fit into the ten minute window. Have you designed the data warehouse model yet? Medical data warehouses are tricky because the data sources are very 'key/value', which is not the easiest thing to model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick. We are in a very initial stage but I have designed data model to begin with. I have also identified a date field which is updated every time a new row is added to the tables or any old row is updated.(I am new to DWH but I have worked on the same health Database for which we need to design the DWH) I just need to plan the process now and try to create a temp DWH with may be 2-3 tables to test how we can extract the data from Oracle and load them in SQL Server DWH using SSIS Packages. Do you have any recommendations to my questions?

Comment: I have added some detail but really this question is far too broad

Answer (score 4):

This is a very broad question and you haven't yet got into the deep complexities of 
mapping source medical data to a business friendly star schema.

Where did the data warehouse requirement and the ten minute requirement come from? What's the more important driver for the business: having a latency of only ten minutes, or having consistent correct information? I guess the focus is operational (admittance etc.), not financial or HR?

> When extracting the data from Oracle should I import the complete
>   tables or should I get only selected columns which I want? For example
>   : If I have person,address,facility_hist tables should I join them in
>   the extracting package and only get the selected columns? or should I
>   extract all three tables separately in staging area and then combine
>   them and load them in SQL Server.

In an "ODS Layer" approach, there is a full replica of Oracle tables in your SQL Database (usually in a different SQL Server schema. Note "schema" in Oracle and SQL Server mean subtly different things)

An ODS is basically a copy of the source system. If you want 10 minute refreshes then you will need to do incremental (changes only) loads into your ODS. To do that you need to know what changed in the source since you last loaded your ODS. If there is a 'last changed' field in the source, this is easy. Otherwise it gets very difficult.

The ODS approach aligns with a 'batch load' pattern, when data is batched through in layers. An ODS allows you to test and troubleshoot at different layers.

The ODS approach is different to a 'stream' approach, which supports real time reporting, but contains isolated transformation rules all along the stream.

> > Indexes should be created on the target tables or while extracting the data?

Indexes should generally be disabled/dropped on tables before data loads then rebuilt afterwards

> I am planning to do the initial load in batches by using the
>   create_dt_tm for the records and load the data in months. Once
>   everything is loaded, we are planning to use the updt_dt_tm and load
>   any updates done in last 10 minutes.

I don't know what `updt_dt_tm` is but that sounds like a good idea

> Is connecting to the database a good idea to get the data every 10 minutes?

Yes. How else will you get the data out?

In summary, focus on getting a ten minute ODS replica working, based off incremental loads. Then your next step is to transform the data from the ODS to the star schema.

> how we can extract the data from Oracle and load them in SQL Server DWH using SSIS Packages.

Again this is a very broad question and I could type a whole approach for you here but I don't think my paying clients would appreciate it

There are *many* design patterns. I prefer an ELT (Extract Load Transform) ODS approach which is T-SQL heavy but in my experience is the best approach. In this approach you load and stage records updated in the last couple of days then merge them into the ODS tables using SQL

Just one lat thing: I see in your question history you are asking about conditional splits. I just need to warn you that if you start using conditional splits and lookups in SSIS to load your data, you're package is probably not going to perform very well and you're going to end up with something really complex and it's going to blow out your ten minutes.

It really comes down to the ETL vs ETL approach. If you are not comfortable with SQL then you'll probably have to use the ELT (all login in SSIS package) approach. But in my experience it becomes slow and difficult to maintain

Comment: The 10 minute requirement came from the hospitals and people working on gathering data and analyzing data. That was the reason this project started. 
"Indexes should generally be disabled/dropped on tables before data loads then rebuilt afterwards"

Comment: Are you saying that we should be removing the indexes in the staging DB every 10 minutes we are extracting the data and then once its extracted we should be rebuilding them? Sorry if thats a basic question.. 

 updt_dt_tm is update date time of the records.. 

I think I framed the question the wrong way. I just needed to ask the efficient ways to extract the data from the DB as its a PROD DB and we dont to impact the performance of the DB by querying it every 10 minutes

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You have to try it and see. It depends on the size of your tables, how many indexes etc. The best way to minimise impact on your source database is to ensure there is an index on `updt_dt_tm` so that extracting data is as efficient as possible. Then get that data locally into SQL Server and run expensive transformations on the SQL Server side without impacting the source. That's the ODS approach: get the data off the source. You could also just create some kind of mirror of the Oracle database and work off that

Answer (score 1):

I recently built a solution with similar requirements but my solution replicates over a 100 tables from an Oracle EBS DB to a "Live BI" system with only a few seconds of latency.  However, I chose Vertica as the DB and StreamSets for data intergration.

StreamsSets is designed for streaming and with a single data pipeline, it can process all of my tables.  It figures out all the columns and even what keys to use for updates on the target DB.

I used Vertica because a columnar, MPP database can provide 100x the performance of a row-wise DB and doesn't use indexes that need rebuilt.  Vertica is more mature than more recent cloud-only columnar DB like RedShift, Snowflake, and BigQuery and has designed a write-optimized-store in memory and read-optimized-store on disk so that writes are super fast. Behind the scenes a tuple mover process compacts written data every five minutes but queries always return the latest data by merging these two areas.

We approched our table design as a ODS/data lake but I did chose to exclude columns that were 100% empty (StreamSets just skips columns not in the target).  I do have some table that are periodically refreshed like my calendar table and unit of measure conversions because a view could impact performance and they don't change frequently.  Otherwise I leave the tables alone and use views and the Oracle BI semantic layer data modeling to build the user friendly view for the business. Because the DB is columnar, my queries are very fast even though the tables frequently have well over 100 columns.

Comment: Thanks Dan. We have to use SQL Server as the destination DB as the team knows how to use it and my manager doesn't want to change that. But we can change the data loading tool if there is faster and more flexible tool than SSIS to extract from Oracle and load into SQL Server.

Comment: I understand.  StreamSets Data Collector can target SQL Server just as easily as Vertica. I also should mention that it is 100% open source.  It only requires a JDBC driver for the DB. It also has a change data capture step for Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, and a few other DB.  We have turned on change tracking for a series of tables in our MES system on MS SQL Server so that we can replicate them.  For all CDC steps, it leverages DB specific tech (LogMiner for Oracle) to detect inserts, updates, or deletes on tables you point it at and performs the same operation on whatever DB you target.